# Continuously fade in and out random pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get make a function that will continuously fade in and out pictures that are randomly selected,  so that the same picture doesn't come up twice.  I can get it to fade out / change image / fade in once if it is clicked with

```
$("img").click(function() { CODE });
```

but I have to click the image each time, and  I am getting stuck trying to make it into a function that is called when the page has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    while (picPicker1 === picPicker2) {
      picPicker2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 1);
    }

    var source = pics[picPicker2];
    $("img").attr("src", source);
    $("img").fadeIn(2000);
    picPicker1 = picPicker2;
  });
});
```

`pics[]` is an array with the web addresses of five different pictures.  I also tried using `setInterval`, but that didn't work either.  New to all of these languages so thank you in advance for your patience!

Comment: Look at the `setInterval()` js function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` was the correct function to use. The code you've provided in your question is missing a closing `});`.

Here's some basic code that makes use of `setInterval` to change the image:

**JQuery:**

```
var pics = [
  "https://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000",
  "https://placehold.it/350x150/00ff00",
  "https://placehold.it/350x150/0000ff",
  "https://placehold.it/350x150/F2F5A9",
  "https://placehold.it/350x150/FF00FF",
];

setInterval(function() {
  var picPicker2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1);

  var source = pics[picPicker2];
  $("img").fadeOut(500).attr("src", source).fadeIn(500);
}, 2000);
```

**Note:** The images will repeat occasionally, but the code I've provided is only a base for you to improve upon.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/bgmmfyyc/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `setInterval()`, `for (x = 5; x > 0; x ++) {}`, `var x = 0; do {} while (x = 0);`, or `var x = 0; while (x = 0) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var picPicker, source;

 function generateImage() {
    $("img").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    picPicker = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));

    source = 'https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=' + picPicker;
  
    $("img").attr("src", source);
    $("img").fadeIn(2000);
  });
  
  setTimeout(generateImage, 5000);
 }
 
 generateImage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300/?image=1">
```